# How can I scale points in Dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, r, dygraphs

I am using the great dygraphs package for R (https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/)

My code as of right now is:

```
james<-mtcars[c("mpg","drat")]
james$date<-seq(from=as.Date("2013-05-16"),to=as.Date("2013-06-16"),by="days")
x <- xts::xts(james$mpg, order.by = james$date)
p <- dygraphs::dygraph(x, main = "mpg over time", xlab = "Date", ylab = "mpg") %>%
     dygraphs::dyRangeSelector() %>% 
     dyOptions(drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2)
p
```

I want to scale the size of points in p by `james$drat`, rather than having it fixed at 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dygraphs javascript library has no option for varying point size within each series. A quite simple workaround is to create one series for every point size.
Let us say we want 5 different point sizes, varying with `james$drat`. First, we create a binned variable with values 1-5 depending on the value of `drat`:

```
drat_binned <- cut(james$drat, breaks=5, labels=1:5)
```

Then we create 5 copies of the plot's y variable (`james$mpg`):

```
james_new_variables <- matrix(rep(james$mpg, 5), nrow=nrow(james))
```

For column number 1 we keep only the `mpg` values where `drat_binned`equals 1, and correspondingly for columns number 2-5. The variables are then added to the original data set:

```
for (i in 1:5)
  james_new_variables[drat_binned != i, i] <- NA
james <- data.frame(james, james_new_variables)
```

Then we make a new `dygraph` of the original variable plus the new variables (by default named `X1-X5`):

```
x <- xts::xts(james[,c("mpg","X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")], order.by = james$date)
p <- dygraphs::dygraph(x, main = "mpg over time", xlab = "Date", ylab = "mpg") %>%
  dygraphs::dyRangeSelector() %>% 
  dySeries("mpg") %>%
  dySeries("X1", color="blue", drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2) %>%
  dySeries("X2", color="blue", drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 3) %>%
  dySeries("X3", color="blue", drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 4) %>%
  dySeries("X4", color="blue", drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 5) %>%
  dySeries("X5", color="blue", drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 6) %>%
p
```

Not very elegant, but sort of works. The only thing that reveals the trick used is the legend, which becomes messed up with the X1-X5 labels.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I have found a potential solution using `drawPointCallback`.  I hope it helps someone out there.  You could choose a scale either in R or JavaScript if you did not want to use the raw number.

```
library(dygraphs)

james<-mtcars[c("mpg","drat")]
james$date<-seq(from=as.Date("2013-05-16"),to=as.Date("2013-06-16"),by="days")
x <- xts::xts(james$mpg, order.by = james$date)
p <- dygraphs::dygraph(x, main = "mpg over time", xlab = "Date", ylab = "mpg") %>%
  dygraphs::dyRangeSelector() %>% 
  dyOptions(drawPoints = TRUE)
p %>%
  dyCallbacks("drawPointCallback" = sprintf(
    "
function(g, name, ctx, canvasx, canvasy, color, radius, index) {
  var drat = %s;
  radius = drat[index];
  return Dygraph.Circles.DEFAULT(g, name, ctx, canvasx, canvasy, color, radius)
}
",
    jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars$drat)
    )
  )
```